# Nuxt val.replace is not a function when get asyncData from APIs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, meta, head, asyncdata

my intention is to get some data from api,

then put in the head(){} to set description and title,

but it keep telling me val.replace is not a function,

here is my code

```
async mounted() {
...await call api...
    if (resDataGetNewsInfo.return_code === 0) {
      vm.newsInfoObj = resDataGetNewsInfo.return_msg;
    } else {
      ...
    }
```

...

```
  asyncData() {
    return {
      newsInfoObj: '',
    };
  },
```

...

```
  head() {
    return {
      description: this.newsInfoObj.news_short_desc,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          property: 'og:title',
          content: this.newsInfoObj.news_title,
        },
```

Uncaught TypeError: val.replace is not a function

thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not the way to use `asyncData`.

Your API call should be called inside the `asyncData` and then return your data